# How to provide correct hostname in gitlab confirmation email?

Tags: email, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I've just installed gitlab in a fresh ubuntu 14.04 VPS and playing around it.
Everything goes fine mostly but I'm run into some problems mentioned below. When I'm creating a new user gitlab sends me an email with wrong hostname in confirmation link

```
http://example/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=Lo1x_LndoJdhGH2KxXXX
```

rather then

```
http://example.org/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=Lo1x_LndoJdhGH2KxXXX
```

I've already changed hostname in `/etc/hostname` (after gitlab configuration frankly)
I also changed `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` to provide correct `external_url` and restarted the server, but I still receive confirmation emails with wrong hostname in confirmation link. Why this happen? How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I've found an answer here https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/issues/244. This guy run into much more subtle situation.
All I need to do in my particular situation is to run

```
sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
```

after editing `external_url` in `/etc/giltab/gitlab.rb`