# Gitlab 'Command line instructions' showing incorrect information

Tags: git, installation, gitlab

I am hosting an on-prem gitlab environment at my company.  The gitlab server is sitting on a synology NAS box, and is accessed via a forward-lookup zone and cname which (gitlab.) points to the nasbox.

Anyway, this all works fine, I am able to get to the gitlab server via this forward-lookup-zone and cname, and I can even push to it with this information.

My issue is that the "Command line instructions" that are shown when creating a new, empty project are not correct.

For example...
The "git clone" command shows 'git clone http://:30000...' when I would like it to show 'git clone http://gitlab.:30000...'

Is there a way to correct this?  The information that is currently shown is not correct and doesn't even work, leading to confusion.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32481886/7976758 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/38738170/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgitlab%5D+hostname

Comment: My gitlab env is hosted inside a docker container, so Im not sure how to access the configuration files required to fix this.